# Mount Mac OS Extended Journaled Filesystem and share via AFP

Tags: mac, file-sharing, hfs+

I see that I can mount a Mount Mac OS Extended Journaled Filesystem on Ubuntu (it seems, after disabling journaling), and that I can share resources on the network via AFP using netatalk.

My question is -- can I take a disk with an existing Mac OS Extended filesystem, mount it on a server running Ubuntu 16.04 after disabling journaling, and make that filesystem available to Mac's on my network via AFP using netatalk?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I supposed it would be possible to host an HFS+ partition over AFP/netatalk, but a more permanent solution would be to copy the files from the HFS+ partition over to an EXT4 directory. In addition, it's far simpler to setup a Samba server on Linux and the Macs should still be able to access the files.

Adding Samba to your server isn't too difficult, as outlined [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!)

1. Install samba with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install samba`
2. Create a new samba user with `sudo smbpasswd -a <user_name>`
3. Make the directory to be shared `mkdir /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>`

At this point, you should copy the files over to this directory so that they will be shared on the samba server.

You will have to disable journaling on the Mac to mount the drive on Ubuntu. The first answer at https://superuser.com/q/84446/663873 descibes how to disable journaling

On your Mac

1. Open Disk Utility under Applications -> Utilities
2. Seect the volume to disable journaling on.
3. Choose Disable Journaling from the File menu. (On later Mac OS versions you'll have to hold down the option button when you click the File menu. Or if you like <kbd>Apple</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)

After you connect the drive, mount the partition, as another answer on the question says:

First, make sure that you have hfsprogs installed. Example installation command:

`sudo apt-get install hfsprogs`

Next, mount or remount the HFS+ drive; commands need to be as follows:

`sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdx# /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>`

Then we continue setting up the Samba server

4. Backup the default samba config file `sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf_backup`
5. Edit the file `sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf`

Add this to the end

```
[<folder_name>]
path = /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>
valid users = <user_name>
read only = no
```

Then restart Samba with

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Then to access the files from a Mac, go to the file manager select Go > Connect To

And enter 
`smb://<ip of server>`

Comment: Dear Evan, Thank you for your reply! Indeed, I could migrate the content to an ext4 filesystem. However, I wanted to maintain the content on a Mac OS Journaled filesystem for situations that require the drive to be connected directly to a Mac (for applications where network access isn't fast enough, such as video editing).

Comment: @Maverick Ok then, I changed it. You can just mount the HFS+ drive at the folder to be shared over Samba